# Trying to improve the server response time

Tags: webserver, page-speed, testing, load-time

I have used the [Google Developer PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) Test and it suggests this:

```
Improve server response time
Suggestions for this page
Long web server response times delay page loading. Reduce your  response times to make your page load faster.

http://109.205.137.148/images/center_arrows.png (1.4 seconds)
http://109.205.137.148/images/ss00.jpg (2.4 seconds)
http://109.205.137.148/images/thumbup.png (0.40 seconds)
http://109.205.137.148/images/wait.gif (1.4 seconds)
```

Since those images are really small I'm wondering if my problem is the VPS I have contracted.

Note: the VPS I have contracted is inside my country.

Comment: the pagespeed test is done user-side, and those images are popping up fine over here. Perhaps you are experiencing some lag with your ISP... At least over here, I am getting anything between 50 and 100 milliseconds for the image to show.

Comment: Please do various checks using http://www.webpagetest.org/ using multiple servers near to the location of your server location... Use 20mbit connection, and report back your findings.. Provide the test URLS that they produce.